# display all the images except from particular bucket display name in android

Tags: android, android-image

I am displaying all the sd card images in grid view.The thing is I have to display all the images which are there on external storage of the device and at the same time not to display the camera images.I know that for this I need to get either camera bucket id or bucket display name.I am not getting how to do this.So can anyone please help me how to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.You might need to modify this

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPathOfAllImages(Activity activity) {
        ArrayList<String> absolutePathOfImageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        String nameOfFile = null;
        String absolutePathOfFileWithoutFileName = null;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index;
        int column_displayname;
        int lastIndex;



            uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                    MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };

            cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);

            column_displayname = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);


            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index);
                nameOfFile = cursor.getString(column_displayname);

                lastIndex = absolutePathOfImage.lastIndexOf(nameOfFile);

                lastIndex = lastIndex >= 0 ? lastIndex
                        : nameOfFile.length() - 1;

                absolutePathOfFileWithoutFileName = absolutePathOfImage
                        .substring(0, lastIndex);


                    if (absolutePathOfImage != null&& !absolutePathOfImage.equals("/sdcard/DCMI/")) {
                        absolutePathOfImageList.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                    }

            }
```

Use absolutePathOfImageList to populate your grid view

Answer (score 1):

Usualy camera images are stored in a particular folder,DCMI folder.Just dont display images  that are in the DCMI folder,skip that folder while you search for images in your sd card

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that